# How to add column inside ListView.Builder Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
     childern:<Widget>[
         //Widget 1
         //Widget 2

           Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                 
                    //Widget 3
                     //Widget 4
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
     ]
);
```

So the problem is that I am getting error

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints
> are unbounded

I understood that Column inside ListView.Builder is **unbounded** so its throwing error.
But I cant give manual/hardcoded height to that column. What approach I should use?

Comment: This code works fine.

Comment: @Mobina Column inside the ListView builder throws error

Comment: The problem is with the other widgets that you didn't include in this code. This code throws no error.

Comment: @Mobina is right, there must be an error in other parts of the code. A working project can be found here: https://codepen.io/theredcap/pen/oNxbgWv

Answer (score -2):

As of Dart 2.3 you use the spread operator insted

Eg

```
...[for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Text(i.toString())]
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question at all!